# Http request automatically becomes https

Tags: asp.net, http, https

I'm running an asp.net core web application secured by ssl.

I need to send an ajax request to a local-network device which does not offer https.

So I try to send an ajax http request to a local ip adress (eg. http://192.168.1.30/hello-world) from a https browser window showing my web-app.

The url of the ajax request always gets converted into http**s**://192.168.1.30/hello-world (which does not exist).

Is there anyway to avoid this? The device does not offer https and I can't send a local request from an insecured source.

Thank you!

Comment: Who is converting http to https? The browser does? I doubt... The browser just execute java script as is... it doesn't go and change the code.

Comment: Try to use another browser. It might cache the redirect with a 301 response.